# How to override the email being sent for the user email verification step in django-rest-auth so that it's more mobile app apropriate

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, email-verification

I am working on a django rest application which is aimed to be consumed through a mobile application.

We are currently using dj-rest-auth for handling the authentication process but I have a problem with the email verification part.

The default email that is being sent is something like:

> please follow this url to verify your account.

But since the client for us is a mobile application what we want to have is something like:

> Please use this token with the application to verify your email.

The problem is that the email is sending to the user a url to follow, The url itself contains the necessary token which is needed for the rest call to verify the user and although I can override the email being send though providing a different `email_confirmation_message.txt` but I can't seem to get just the token because I the only variable the is pre-configured there for me is the one called active_url.

Do you have any suggestion on how to go with this or any direction would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

django-rest-auth uses django allauth under the hood so you can override any of the default allauth templates.
For the email templates see [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-email)

For the verification email you will have to override
`account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt`

Answer (score 0):

After some research I dig into the code of dj-rest-auth and found out that  The VerifyEmailSerializer has one field which instead of what I though is called `key = serializers.CharField()` so you can use the `{{key}}` variable within the email to get the hexadecimal coded needed!